# Form not running PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I'm working on an assignment for my class in which I am supposed to take a username and password and check it against a list contained in a table on a database I am connecting too.

Problem is when I am clicking the submit button nothing is happening I think this is likely to be some sort of error in syntax. Since I am new to PHP there is a good possibility it is something obvious, but not so much to me.

I have my database data stored in two PHP arrays (one for each field). I then converted the arrays to json which I will use in my JavaScript function that will be checked against the user inputted data.

I am including a form, a PHP script, and a JavaScript script in one document could this cause the issue?

Here is my code and thank you for any help!

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
/*config is included in order to protect my login info*/
require('config.php');
Echo "Project 4";

/*SQL connection*/
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

/*Checking Connection*/
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM p4Data";
$data2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

/*Display Data*/
echo "<table border = 1 style='float:left'>
<tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
</tr>";

//Array Declarations
$usernameArr = [];
$passwordArr = []; 

while($records = mysqli_fetch_array($data2)){
  array_push($usernameArr,$records["username"]);
  array_push($passwordArr,$records["password"]);
}
echo "</table>";

//JSON Conversion
$usernameJson = json_encode($usernameArr);
$passwordJson = json_encode($passwordArr);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>



<!-- JAVA SECTION -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $usernameJson; ?>');
  var obj2 = JSON.parse('<?= $passwordJson; ?>');

  function verifUser(){
    var usernameData = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var passwordData = document.getElementById("password").value;
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){

      if(usernameData == obj[i]){
        alert("Username verfied at " + i);
        indexLocated = i;
        break;
       }
      }
    }
</script>


<form name='form-main'>
  Username: <input type="text" id="username"><br>
  Password: <input type="password" id="password"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Login >>" id="submitButton" 
onclick="verifUser()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you run your code do you see any errors in the PHP error log or in the browser's developer console (which in most browsers can be opened by pressing F12)? Not what you're asking, but note that sending all of the user names and passwords to the browser is a **terrible breach of security.** Even aside from the fact that unencrypted passwords shouldn't be stored at all, you should send just the entered value to the server and validate it there, not send all of the passwords to the browser.

Comment: This is all backwards. You should be doing a simple query for the username and password match in database, not sending the whole database to browser

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. So you mean to send the user entered data to the PHP script and compare it with the members of the arrays I setup. I should forget the whole json part. And need not to worry about encrypting the passwords since they are just for learning.

Comment: Yes, send user entered data to the PHP. But you shouldn't need the arrays, you should be able to include the entered values in your SELECT statement. (Just don't concatenate the values as strings, because of [this](https://xkcd.com/327/); use a parameterised query.)

Comment: Will do, I'm going to rest on it and look it over in the morning. Thanks mate.

Answer (score -1):

You can use post method to get the value of user input like this

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

and use this php code to get value when form is submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username_input = $_POST['username'];
$password_input = $_POST['password'];
}
```

Then make a query to sql where username = $username and password = $password. Like below

```
$sql query = " SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE username = $username and password = $password";
```

And use

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql_query);
```

Now do a check of $num_rows = 1 that means input username and password is valid else echo Not valid

```
if($num_rows = 1){
**some code **
}else{
echo "Invalid information provided";
};
```